# List equality in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Making a KMeans clustering algorithm here:
Getting stuck on list equality

```
#clusters = [[],[]]
prevclusters = list(clusters) # Making a new list using clusters elements.
.....
clusters[loc].append(inputs[i]) # Modifying clusters in a for loop
....
# Now, clusters = [[[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[3, 7], [4, 5], [5, 5]]]
if prevclusters == clusters: # Gives True, why ?
```

Comment: To see the same effect, try `L = [[]] * 4; print(L); L[0].append(1); print(L)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing the item at `loc` in `cluster`, both lists still reference the same sublist, which has been modified. You may want to `copy.deepcopy` the list when creating `prevclusters`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

prevclusters = deepcopy(clusters)
```